# regex pattern in java crashes with just one specific text

Tags: java, regex

I have the following pattern to be checked against any text:

```
public static boolean endWithLinkOrHashAt(String commentstr)
{
    String urlPattern = "^[@|#]((?:\\w+\\s?){1,}).*:\\s[^?]?((?:\\w+\\s?){1,})[^?]((?:http|https):\\/\\/\\S+)(\\s[@|#]\\w+){0,}[^?]$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("yes");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now when I try it with the following text the program does not do anything, the console run forever without any result or any error:

```
endWithLinkOrHashAt("#BREAKING: @Baird resigning in aftermath of controversial win over @pmharper in game of #Trouble (with the pop-o-matic bubble) #cdnpoli");
```

Is anything wrong with my regex(but it works with other texts and it seems that it has problem with just this specific text)

Update:

Here is what I want my pattern to check against:

```
@ or # + 1 or 2 words + : + 1 words or more + link + nothing or any words that has # or @ at the beginning
```

Comment: It sounds like your expression has an infinite loop in it.

Comment: @Tyler But it works fine with other texts perfectly and has this problem just with the specified text

Comment: I suspect there's a specific text configuration that causes a loop. I don't have time to look into your specific example, but I'd suggest slowly paring down your example string until the problem stops happening. That should help you identify what characters are correlated with the problem.

Comment: @Tyler: if one implements a regex engine with the features Java offers correctly, one can do so such that no regex can get into an infinite loop. So in that case there is a "bug" or at least a weak point in the Java regex engine.

Comment: True but it is easy to implement patterns with lots of backtracking that will result in an exponential runtime

Comment: CATASTROPHIC BACKTRACKING!!!!!!

Comment: You do not have a link here in the input string. Besides, the words at the end are not all starting with `#` or `@`. Perhaps, you need [`(?i)^[@#](\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?)\\s*:\\s*(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*)\\s*(https?://\\S*)?((?:\\s+(?=[#@])\\S+)*)\\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/hJ4rD3/1).

Comment: @stribizhev I know that is why the program should return false but apparently it runs forever without returning anything I will check ur pattern right now

Comment: I have fixed the escaping slashes in the comment above

Comment: @stribizhev thank u but when I try yours with the above text it returns yes which should not because above text does not match with the pattern for example it does not have any link

Comment: Then remove `?` after `https?://\\S*)`: [`(?i)^[@#](\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?)\\s*:\\s*(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*)\\s*(https?://\\S*)((?:\\s+(?=[#‌​@])\\S+)*)\\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/oH6iN0/1).

Comment: @stribizhev the same thing happens for your regex as well when I try it with this text: @ z0mgItsHutch leaping into identity politics, yep smart move #sarcasm... program runs for ever

Comment: No it does not. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/oH6iN0/3).

Comment: Sorry u are right I double checked and worked !!!! though still no idea why my regex did not work on that specific text, but thanks a lot for ur awesome regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem with your regex is that it caused catastrophic backtracking. The root cause it nested quantifiers.

I suggest using a more linear regex:

```
(?i)^[@#](\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?)\\s*:\\s*(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*)\\s*(https?://\\S*)((?:\\s+(?=[#@])\\S+)*)\\s*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oH6iN0/3)

It is basically the same regex I suggested before, I just added more whitespace to it.

Comment: quick question: what is the role of this: (?i)

Comment: It is the inline version of the case insensitive flag.